# How to filter out the rows with the latest and earliest dates for each item_id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter out the rows with the latest and earliest dates for each item_id using pandas. Thanks in advance for your kind help :)

| item_id | favorite | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1049977 | 8 | 2022-06-09 |
| 1049977 | 8 | 2022-06-10 |
| 1049977 | 8 | 2022-06-11 |
| 1049977 | 8 | 2022-06-12 |
| 1611924 | 168 | 2022-06-09 |
| 1611924 | 168 | 2022-06-10 |
| 1611924 | 168 | 2022-06-11 |
| 1611924 | 168 | 2022-06-12 |
| 1611924 | 168 | 2022-06-13 |

The ideal output is:

| item_id | favorite | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1049977 | 8 | 2022-06-09 |
| 1049977 | 8 | 2022-06-12 |
| 1611224 | 168 | 2022-06-09 |
| 1611924 | 168 | 2022-06-13 |

Raw data is here:

```
item_id,favorite,date
1049977,8,2022-06-09
1049977,8,2022-06-10
1049977,8,2022-06-11
1049977,8,2022-06-12
1611924,168,2022-06-09
1611924,168,2022-06-10
1611924,168,2022-06-11
1611924,168,2022-06-12
1611924,168,2022-06-13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[df.groupby('item_id')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(x.max()) | x.eq(x.min()))]
```

Output:

```
   item_id  favorite       date
0  1049977         8 2022-06-09
3  1049977         8 2022-06-12
4  1611924       168 2022-06-09
8  1611924       168 2022-06-13
```

Answer (score 2):

This is best done using groupby operations. When starting out it might be tempting to do this with a loop but that will seriously impact performance as the number of rows grows.

Using groupby methods .first() and .last() gives you the first and last entry. Note that you need to ensure that your dataframe is sorted by whichever column designate your date for this to work.

.concat is just an easy way to put the results together into one df. There might be nicer options.

This snippet:

```
pd.concat([
    df.groupby('item_id').first(),
    df.groupby('item_id').last()
    ]).sort_index()
```

Gives me this output:

```
         favorite        date
item_id                      
1049977         8  2022-06-09
1049977         8  2022-06-12
1611924       168  2022-06-09
1611924       168  2022-06-13
```

Comment: If there are multiple items with the same max/min date, then only one max/min per group will be selected using this method~

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the group with max, min `date` value in `groupby.apply` or in `transform(min)` and `transform(max)`

```py
out = (df.groupby('item_id')
       .apply(lambda g: g[g['date'].isin([g['date'].min(), g['date'].max()])])
       .reset_index(drop=True))

# or

groups = df.groupby(['item_id'])['date']
out = df[(df['date']==groups.transform(min)) | (df['date']==groups.transform(max))]
```

```
print(out)

   item_id  favorite        date
0  1049977         8  2022-06-09
3  1049977         8  2022-06-12
4  1611924       168  2022-06-09
8  1611924       168  2022-06-13
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require the input dataframe to be sorted. For each `item_id`, it obtains the index values of the rows where dates are either earliest (minimum) or latest (maximum) and then filters the original dataframe using those index values.

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('item_id').date.agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).values.ravel()]

    item_id favorite          date
0   1049977        8    2022-06-09
3   1049977        8    2022-06-12
4   1611924      168    2022-06-09
8   1611924      168    2022-06-13
```

Comment: What, (if any) difference is there between `ravel()` and `flatten()` here?

Comment: @BeRT2me, no difference as far as I know: same result, timing nearly identical.

Comment: If there are multiple items with the same max/min date, then only one max/min per group will be selected using this method~

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [1049977, 1049977, 1049977, 1049977,1611924,1611924,1611924,1611924,1611924],
                 'favorite': [8,8,8,8,168,168,168,168,168],
                 'date': ['2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-11', '2022-06-12',
                          '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-11', '2022-06-12', '2022-06-13']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


df['nrows'] = df.groupby(['item_id', 'favorite']).cumcount()+1

df['max_row'] = df.groupby(['item_id', 'favorite'])['nrows'].transform('max')
df['min_row'] = df.groupby(['item_id', 'favorite'])['nrows'].transform('min')

df['flag_min'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['nrows']==x['min_row']) else 0, axis = 1)
df['flag_max'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['nrows']==x['max_row']) else 0, axis = 1)

df1 = df[(df['flag_min']== 0) & (df['flag_max']== 0)].drop(['nrows','max_row', 'min_row', 'flag_min', 'flag_max'], axis = 1)

print(df1)
```